# increase the height of a slider in Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I'm surprised this question hasn't come up anywhere.

Using CSS, how can I increase the height of a slider?

This is too skinny:

[image]

Using firebug, I found what I thought might be the right element.

[image]

But putting this in my `shinycss.css` file:

`.jslider {height: 200%;}`

or

`.jslider-value{height: 200%;}`

or even

`.jslider shiny-bound-input {max-height: 200px;}`

did no good. It dawned on me that perhaps I am futilely just manipulating containers and not the actual slider object with CSS.

I'm obviously looking in the wrong place, and clearly I'm new to CSS. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Putting in percent values for height may not work if the parent element containing it has a fixed max-height. Try changing the max-height of parent element and then try giving a percent value.

You can always give a fixed height:

```
.jslider { height:100px; }
```